# ios 8 devices detection issue in iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: macos, ios8

When my ios8 devices are connected, there is a "?" instead of a device icon with my ios6 & ios7 devices. Each ios8 device has an empty console tab.

All informations, configuration profiles, provisioning profiles and apps are availlable. Only the console tab  has no content.

ios8 devices are used for developpement and Test purposes.

- OSX 10.10
- Itunes 12.0.1.26
- Xcode 6.1

Any ideas ?